# JavaFX apply effect to everything except specific nodes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, nodes

I want to highlight certain Shapes by blurring the whole scene except these specific nodes.

I've tried creating an ArrayList containing all nodes in the scene, removing the ones I want to stay sharp and blurring the rest. The problem I had with that approach is that the Shapes are inside a few layers of panes which get blurred due to being contained in my ArrayList.

My methods looked more or less like this:

```
private void createBlurredNodesArrayList(){
    for (Node node : borderPane.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        blurredNodes.add(node);
    }
    blurredNodes.removeAll(colorCircles);
    blurredNodes.removeAll(playerNameTexts);
}

private void blur() {
    GaussianBlur gb = new GaussianBlur(BLURRADIUS);
    for (Node blurredNode : blurredNodes) {
        blurredNode.setEffect(gb);
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant solution (e.g. just getting all Nodes on the "lowest level" of a scene and removing the shapes) or do I need an ugly, hard-coded one?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have code to share?

Comment: Not all of the original code is left, but I added some to the post.

Comment: Which nodes you do not apply the effect ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is remove all Parent nodes of the nodes you don't want blurred, and if they have parents, remove those. You could try something like

```
Node nodeToRemove = colorCircles;
while(nodeToRemove !=null){
    blurredNodes.remove(nodeToRemove);
    nodeToRemove = nodeToRemove.getParent());
}
```